# Calculating the order of conjugacy classes in $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For $A_5$, if I have the conjugacy classes $\sigma_1=(1 2)(3  4)$ and $\sigma_2 =(123)$, I see in my notes that $|\sigma_1|=15$ and $|\sigma_2|=20$. But I can not figure out why. How are these calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Kenny Lau, conjugation does not affect cycle type. Namely, for a permutation $g \in S_n$ we have:

$$g(1\,2)(3\,4)g^{-1} = (g(1)\,g(2))(g(3)\,g(4))$$
$$g(1\,2\,3)g^{-1} = (g(1)\,g(2)\,g(3))$$

So for $(1 \,2)(3 \,4)$ just count the number of permutations consisting of two disjoint transpositions. Pick two elements for the first transposition on $5 \choose 2$ ways, and from the remaining $3$ elements pick two $3 \choose 2$ in two ways. Finally divide by two because disjoint transpositions commute so it is not importatnt which one is the first:

$$\frac{1}{2} {5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2} = 15$$

For $(1\,2\,3)$ just count the number of permutations which have one cycle of length $3$. Pick $3$ elements $x, y, z$ from $5$ and arrange them in a cycle as $(x\,y\,z)$ or $(x\,z\,y)$. Every other order is the same permutation as one of these. Therefore:

$$2{5 \choose 2} = 20$$

---

You can also use the [orbit-stablizer theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem) to determine these numbers:

Let $A_5$ act on itself by conjugation. Stabilizer of an element $x \in A_5$ is precisely the centralizer $C_{A_5}(x)$ of $x$, i.e. the set of all permutations in $A_5$ which commute with $x$. You are interested in the orbit of the element $(1\,2)(3\,4)$:

$$\operatorname{Orb}\,(1\,2)(3\,4) = \{g(1\,2)(3\,4)g^{-1} : g \in A_n\}$$

The orbit-stabilizer theorem gives:

$$\left|\operatorname{Orb}\,(1\,2)(3\,4)\right| = \left|[A_5 : C_{A_5}(1\,2)(3\,4)]\right| = \frac{\left|A_5\right|}{\left|C_{A_5}(1\,2)(3\,4)\right|}$$

It remains to determine $C_{A_5}(1\,2)(3\,4)$:

We have:

$$g(1\,2)(3\,4)g^{-1} = (g(1)\,g(2))(g(3)\,g(4)) = (1\,2)(3\,4)$$

Therefore, $g$ must be of the form:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = \mathrm{id}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (1\,2)$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (3\,4)$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (1\,2)(3\,4) = g$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (1\,3)(2\,4)$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
4 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (1\,4)(2\,3)$$

But $(1\,2), (3\,4) \notin A_5$ so $\left|C_{A_5}(1\,2)(3\,4)\right| = 4$. Therefore,

$$\left|\operatorname{Orb}\,(1\,2)(3\,4)\right| = \frac{60}{4} = 15$$

Similarly, for $(1\,2\,3)$ we have to determine $C_{A_5}(1\,2\,3)$:

$$g(1\,2\,3)g^{-1} = (g(1)\,g(2)\,g(3))$$

So $g$ must be of the form:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = \mathbb{id}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (1\,3\,2)$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix} = (1\,2\,3) = g$$

so $\left|C_{A_5}(1\,2)(3\,4)\right| = 3$. Therefore:

$$\left|\operatorname{Orb}\,(1\,2\,3)\right| = \frac{60}{3} = 20$$

Answer (score 1):

The conjugacy class of a certain permutation is all the permutations with the same cycle type. The cycle type of $(12)(34)$ is $2+2$, so the number of permutations in the same conjugacy class is $\dfrac{5!}{(2!)^2(2!)} = 15$. The cycle type of $(123)$ is $3$, so the number of permutations in the same conjugacy class is $\dfrac{5!}{3!2!} \times 2 = 20$.

Comment: I don't quite understand where those formulas come from. Is there a generalisation?

Comment: @Leonhard it's basically a problem in combinatorics.